# Formatting list into 3SAT Form

Tags: python, formatting, sat

Been away from python for awhile, so formatting skills are non-existent. Looking to turn something of this format:

```
[[8, -6, -4], [-10, 4, 6], [6, -8, -9]]
```

into something that looks like this:

```
(x8 v ~x6 v ~x4) ^ (~x10 v x4 v x6) ^ (x6 v ~x8 v ~x9)
```

and then be able to reference each number as separate input to be changed to T or F. Any guidance would be appreciaed.

```
import random
def sample():
    nums = random.sample(range(-10, 10), 3)
    return nums

exlist = []
boundary = random.randint(3, 10)
count = 0
while (count < boundary):
    count = count + 1
    exlist.append(sample())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the 0 case seems degenerate in your case, so I assume you don't have 0's (otherwise does it become x0 or ~x0 ?)

Assuming you store T / F in a list like this:

```
 exvalues = [bool(random.randint(0,1)) for _ in range(10)]
```

then you can simply evaluate the expression like this (without having to generate the symbolic expression you are after):

```
all(any(exvalues[x] if x>0 else not exvalues[-x] for x in y) for y in exlist)
```

Explanation: you take the global `and` of all your "sub-expressions", and each sub-expression is the global `or` of the elements (with optional `not` depending on sign).

Comment: I wasnt sure how to generate a random list with negatives and exclude the zero.